# Run a python script as a background service in linux

Tags: python

I am currently using linux. I have a python script which I want to run as a background service such as the script should start to run when I start my machine. 
Currently I am using python 2.7 and the command 'python myscripy.py' to run the script.

Can anyone give an idea about how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: please be more specific, `CentOS` or `Ubuntu` or `Debian`, which version?

Comment: Probably better asked over at ServerFault since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where in the startup process you want your script to run.  If you want your script to start up during the init process, then you can incorporate it into the init scripts in /etc/init.d/  The details will depend on what init system your system is running.  You might be on a system V init (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or on systemd (https://wiki.debian.org/systemd), or possibly some other one.  If you don't need your script to run at the system level, then you could kick the script off when you log in.  To do that, you'd put it in `~/.profile` if you log in using a terminal.  Or, if you use a desktop environment, then you're going to be doing something in ~/.local/XSession (if I recall correctly).  Different desktop environments are going to have different ways to specify what happens when a user logs in.

Hope this helps!  Maybe clarify your needs if you want more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create init script in `/etc/init/` directory
Example:

```
    start on runlevel [2345]
    stop on runlevel [!2345]
    kill timeout 5
    respawn

    script
       exec /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py
    end script
```

Save with `.conf` extension